# Is cubic complexity still the state of the art for LP?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, linear-programming

According to [D. den Hertog, Interior Point Approach to Linear, Quadratic and Convex Programming, 1994](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-94-011-1134-8), a linear program with $n$ variables, $n$ constraints and precision $L$ is solvable in $O(n^3L)$ time. Has that been improved upon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that K.M.Anstreicher has improved the result to $O((n^3/\ln n)L)$ in [Anstreicher, Kurt M. "Linear programming in O ([n3/ln n] L) operations." SIAM Journal on Optimization 9, no. 4 (1999): 803-812.](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S1052623497323194?journalCode=sjope8). I have not read this paper, but I hope that this answer will help you in some extent.